# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop]

Tags: spring, spring-aop, wso2-esb

I m using **Spring AOP** architecture for **Logging and Transaction** management.we are using **WSO2-ESB** container for deploying our service.
Here the XML file which we try to read using **ClassPathXmlApplicationContext()**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
<!-- Complete AOP implementation -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <!-- Aspect -->
    <bean id="logAspect" class="x.y.z.logging.aspect.LoggingAspect" />
    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect id="aspectLoggging" ref="logAspect" >
        <!-- @Before -->
            <aop:pointcut id="pointCutBefore"
                expression="execution(* *(..))" />
            <aop:before method="logBefore" pointcut-ref="pointCutBefore" />
            <!-- @After -->
            <aop:pointcut id="pointCutAfter"
                expression="execution(* *(..))" />
            <aop:after method="logAfter" pointcut-ref="pointCutAfter" />
            <!-- @AfterReturning -->
            <aop:pointcut id="pointCutAfterReturning"
                expression="execution(* *(..))" />
            <aop:after-returning method="logAfterReturning" returning="result" 
                pointcut-ref="pointCutAfterReturning" />
            <!-- @AfterThrowing -->
            <aop:pointcut id="pointCutAfterThrowing"
                expression="execution(* *(..))" />
            <aop:after-throwing method="logAfterThrowing" throwing="error" 
                pointcut-ref="pointCutAfterThrowing"  />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

Actual problem occurred when i start my WSO2-ESB server.
Here i have attached Stacktrace :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop]
Offending resource: file [C:\WSO2\Temp\WSO2ES~1.0\.\repository\conf\bundle-config\logger-aspect.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.mi.logging.core.SpringLoggerUtil.setApplicationContext(SpringLoggerUtil.java:37)
    at com.mi.logging.aspect.activator.LogAspectActivator.start(LogAspectActivator.java:16)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 9 more
```

I m using spring.3.2.5 version and I have reassured that all dependent jar are on classpath.
Please help to resolve this issue. If you have any suggestion or solution then please let me know.
Thnx in advance.

Comment: I would say that there is no spring-aop.jar (or wrong version) on the classpath. Or it isn't readable.

Comment: **spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar** is in the classpath and have the correct version.
If you have any reference or samples of Spring AOP implementation in WSO2-ESB then please share it.

Comment: When is it on the classpath, during building or during deployment?

Comment: we have used Maven for dependency management, so at build time osgi bundle resolve dependency from maven repository.But while deployment time, WSO2 ESB container provide the required jar files so it resolve dependency from there. I m using the same version at both side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred due to it can't find the path/location of **spring-aop-3.0.xsd** from **spring.framework_3.1.0.wso2v1.jar**, which is provided by the WSO2-ESB.
It can be resolved by two ways : 
1) You can add your latest version of spring and set the priority of that jar files.
 [Reference](http://docs.wso2.org/display/AS521/Spring+Applications)

2) You have to just simply follow the steps described below.
You have to add some files into **META-INF** folder of **spring.framework_3.1.0.wso2v1.jar** file.
Steps are shown below. 
i) Create a new file **spring.schemas** and add the content shown below.

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
```

ii) Create a new file **spring.handlers** and add the content shown below.

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop=org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceHandler
```

iii) Create a new file **spring.tooling** and add the content shown below.

```
# Tooling related information for the aop namespace
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop@name=aop Namespace
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop@prefix=aop
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop@icon=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop.gif
```